# Syntax to use retrieve() to deserialize a hash?

Tags: perl, serialization, syntax, data-retrieval, hashref

I'm having trouble understanding how to deserialize a hash with `retrieve()` in Perl (v5.30.0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Storable;

package main;

my %origHash = (key1 => 'data1',
        key2 => 'data2',
        key3 => 'data3',
        key4 => 'data4');

# Retrieve, modify, and retrieve again in %origHash:
printf "Retrieved:  %s\n", $origHash{'key2'};
$origHash{'key2'} = 'data22';   # Modify value
$origHash{'key5'} = 'data5';    # Add new value
printf "Retrieved:  %s %s\n", $origHash{'key2'}, $origHash{'key5'};


# Serialize origHash, store in file 'file':
store \%origHash, 'file';

# Deserialize the hash, now store data in ref 'hashref':
my %hashref = retrieve('file');                                    # Line 24

# Retrieve, modify, and retrieve again in 'hashref':
printf "Retrieved:  %s\n", $hashref{'key2'};                       # Line 27
$hashref{'key2'} = 'data222';   # Modify value
$hashref{'key6'} = 'data6';     # Add new value
printf "Retrieved:  %s %s\n", $hashref{'key2'}, $hashref{'key6'};
```

Output is:

```
me@ubuntu01$ ./SerHash.perl
Retrieved:  data2
Retrieved:  data22 data5
Reference found where even-sized list expected at ./SerHash.perl line 24.
Use of uninitialized value in printf at ./SerHash.perl line 27.
Retrieved:
Retrieved:  data222 data6
me@ubuntu01$
```

So the first half of the script is Perl/Hash 101, demonstrating the simple syntax of making, retrieving from, and modifying values in a hash.  Then I successfully serialize the hash and store in in file `file` with this line: `store \%origHash, 'file';`.

I'm not sure if that worked...?  Here's what I see when I look in `file` after the above `store` command is executed:

```
me@ubuntu01$ more file
pst0
   12345678
data4
data1
data3
data5
data22
me@ubuntu01$
```

Huh.  So my values are there, but where are the keys?

Back to the test script:  After serializing the hash, I try to deserialize the hash from `file` in this line:  `my %hashref = retrieve('file');`  ...although I'm not totally certain about that syntax.  Note that if I try to retrieve data from the deserialized hash with this command...

```
printf "Retrieved:  %s\n", $hashref{'key2'};                       # Line 27
```

...the target value appears to be uninitialized?  Here's the output from that command:

```
Use of uninitialized value in printf at ./SerHash.perl line 27.
Retrieved:
```

Ugh, so that's not great.  I note that I can add new values into the deserialized hash, but that's kinda beside the point if the data from original hash isn't available.

This test code was built [using this tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable), which left me with a shakey understanding of the `retrieve()` function.  According to the documentation:

> To retrieve data stored to disk, use retrieve with a file name. The
> objects stored into that file are recreated into memory for you, and a
> reference to the root object is returned. In case an I/O error occurs
> while reading, undef is returned instead.

So `retrieve()` returns `a reference to the root object[.]`?  Hmmm...  So shouldn't the code be:

```
# Deserialize the hash, now store data in ref 'hashref':
# (***NOTE*** that we define hashref with a '$', not '%' now!)
my $hashref = retrieve('file');                                    # Line 24

# Retrieve, modify, and retrieve again in 'hashref':
printf "Retrieved:  %s\n", $hashref{'key2'};                       # Line 27
$hashref{'key2'} = 'data222';   # Modify value                     # Line 28
$hashref{'key6'} = 'data6';     # Add new value                    # Line 29
printf "Retrieved:  %s %s\n", $hashref{'key2'}, $hashref{'key6'};  # Line 30
```

Now output is:

```
me@ubuntu01$ ./SerHash.perl
Global symbol "%hashref" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %hashref"?) at ./SerHash.perl line 27.
Global symbol "%hashref" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %hashref"?) at ./SerHash.perl line 28.
Global symbol "%hashref" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %hashref"?) at ./SerHash.perl line 29.
Global symbol "%hashref" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %hashref"?) at ./SerHash.perl line 30.
Global symbol "%hashref" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %hashref"?) at ./SerHash.perl line 30.
me@ubuntu01$
```

Gah!  This looks even worse.  I don't understand what is being returned by `retrieve()` nor how to handle it syntactically.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [retrieve](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable) returns a reference, you do want to use a scalar (`$hashref`), as in your 2nd attempt.  The problem is that you are trying to use `$hashref` as a hash.  You need to use dereferencing syntax: `$hashref->{key2}`:

```
my $hashref = retrieve('file');                                    # Line 24

# Retrieve, modify, and retrieve again in 'hashref':
printf "Retrieved:  %s\n", $hashref->{'key2'};                       # Line 27
$hashref->{'key2'} = 'data222';   # Modify value
$hashref->{'key6'} = 'data6';     # Add new value
printf "Retrieved:  %s %s\n", $hashref->{'key2'}, $hashref->{'key6'};
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to say that `retrieve` returns what you put in. And `store` got a hash reference, so `retrieve` gives that reference back to you.

But, Perl has an [experimental `declared_refs` feature](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2018/09/mix-assignment-and-reference-aliasing-with-declared_refs/) where you can assign to a named hash that you are referencing. The `\` in front of the `my` does that. Even though you get a reference from retrieve, it ends up in `%hashref`:

```
use v5.26;
use experimental qw(declared_refs);

\my %hashref = retrieve('file');
```

I find this handy when I go through a list of hashrefs but don't want dereferencing arrows all over the place:

```
foreach \my %h ( @array_of_hashrefs ) {
   say "No arrow for $h{name}"
   }
```